# Why did my hard drive temporarily disappear?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, hard-drive-recovery

On Windows 10, I noticed that my D: was missing. There was no obvious cause for this; in fact, it happened during a day when I was away from the computer.

This Lenovo Ideapad Y700 has a Liteon CV1-8B128 SSD for C: and WDC WD10SPCX-24HWST1 for D:.

Explorer, cmd, and the Disk Management tool showed no sign of D:.

I rebooted to safe mode -- D: was back. I rebooted to regular mode -- it is back.

This is scary. What can cause a disk to disappear like that?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the reasons why a drive could disappear... are many.  Everything from data errors on the drive, to a virus, to intermittent hardware failure.

A good idea is to check the event log and see if there obvious errors.  Check to make sure your anti-virus is up-to-date.  Also check to see if there are updated drivers and firmware (for the drives as well) for your system.  It may not hurt to make a boot disk with the WD's Data Lifeguard utility to do a full scan and check your disk drive.